# Signing android application

Tags: android

I have Google Developer account and I published my first application.

Now I need to publish my second app. Should I sign with the same keystore of my first app.

Please let me know if I'm not clear.

Comment: yes, you should use the same keystore - (key) otherwise it will not allow you to upload, and if tried to install apk direct it will not allow install (update) current app due to different certificate of apks

Comment: You can use the same store, but create a new key to use for each application @Yazan I think he is on about 2 separate applications, not a incremental update on the first.

Comment: @ChrisHandy oh, yes, you are right, i did not notice, so he can use new key, and he can use same key, right?

Comment: I have two separeted applications not the same updated.I used the same keystore and the same keyalias. Is there any problem?

Comment: No problem with using the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the same keystore/key pair is fine for as many apps as you like. I have several that share a keystore/key.

Here is how you should decide if you need a separate key/keystore, in order of importance/concern:

1. Having more than one key or keystore requires remembering passwords and their locations along with securing them. This can be a real pain if you don't update your apps for quite some time. If you lose these, you cannot update/republish your app.
2. It is probably a good idea to use separate keys and the same keystore. This can reduce the likelihood that a hacker could hack both if either is ever hacked. However, this concern is minimal since this scenario is unlikely unless you have a very popular app.
3. If you want to "sell" any of yours apps at some point, you will need to provide a keystore and key to the buyer. Thus, the buyer will know your other app's keystore/key information if they are shared. If you would likely sell apps together, then a common key/keystore is not an issue. If you want to sell them separately, then you should probably have separate keystores and keys. HOWEVER, this is very unlikely to ever be a consideration.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A keystore can old multiple keys.

Use one key for one application.

Now, you can use the same keystore and add a key to it, or create another keystore.